# Android: can I put Global Variables in BroadCastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

I have 2 classes that I want them interacting each other:

First is **Receiver.java**:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private int var = 0;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Bunch of codes here
        method();
        //use var to do something}

    private void method() {
        //do something}

    public void setVar(int i) {
         var= i; }
}
```

Then I have another class that I hope to use to change the variable in `Receiver`, **MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Receiver receiver;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        receiver.setVar; 
        //Bunches of other codes 
}
```

The `Receiver` class listen to SMS message and respond, it extends **BroadcastReceiver**.

The `MainActivity` class change setting in `Receiver` class.

*Since the original code put all variables inside the **onReceive()**:*

- Will I be able to change variable **var** in the `Receiver` class if I put it outside of the method?
- Can `MainActivity` access and change variable in the `Receiver` class?
- Does the **method()** within `Receiver` class work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The answer below is **valid only** for a `BroadcastReceiver` that is to be instantiated and registered/unregistered programmatically within an `Activity` **as OP asked**.*

*The answer **won't work** for a `BroadcastReceiver` that is to be declared within `AndroidManifest` and instantiated by the system, because once `onReceive()` returns the receiver is considered to be no longer active and a new instance will be created next time.*

---

`Receiver` is a regular `Java` object, so

> Will I be able to change variable var in the Receiver class if I put it outside of `onReceive()`?

Yes. `var` is a class member of `Receiver` class.

> Can MainActivity access and change variable in the Receiver class?

Yes. `MainActivity` has the `receiver` reference to a `Receiver` class instance.

> Does the method() within Receiver class work?

Yes. You'll be able to call it after the `receiver` initialization.

Comment: The book I read:**Broadcast Receivers exist only for as long as the onReceive() method is running.
Because of that, you need to write all of your code inside onReceive(). Things like instance variables don’t make sense as they will go out of scope each time onReceive() executes.**does that mean while it's working, it's not recommended to put it outside the onReceive()?